# Call not recognised and use instead Future

Tags: python, tornado

When running my `tornado` script which should send a request and get the body of the response and append this to some html code on a localhost port. However, I get this error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

It turns out from the documentation [Asynchronous HTTP client](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#:%7E:text=Changed%20in%20version%206.0%3A) that the callback has been removed for `Future`

> Changed in version 6.0: The callback argument was removed. Use the returned Future instead.

There are a lack of effective examples and so what is the most appropriate method to use Future in replacement for callback in my script?

```
import asyncio
import os
import json
import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.gen
from tornado.options import define, options
define('port', default = 9060, help="run port 9060", type=int)

class requestFour(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        #arg = self.get_argument('stock')
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        yield client.fetch('https://books.toscrape.com', callback=self.on_response)

    def on_response(self, response):
        body = json.load(response.body)
        self.write("""
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                    <div style="font-size: 72px">%s</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 144px">%.02f</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 24px">tweets per second</div>
                    </div>
                    """ % (body)) 
        self.finish()

def my_app():
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers = [(r'/', requestFour)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    return http_server

async def main():
    app = my_app()
    app.listen(options.port)
    shutdown_event = asyncio.Event()
    await shutdown_event.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Do you understand how to use a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html) *in general*? How exactly did you [try to look](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+Future+tutorial) for examples?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I admit I only looked at the Future from the documentation for tornado and did not suspect there was a pythonic version. It did mention something similar but I assumed they were different. Thanks for sharing these, in the meantime I will read into your selected articles and perhaps update with an example which includes Future if I find difficulty.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do not understand Future after reading the article you suggested, the lack of examples with tornado make it difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `self.on_response` directly:

```py
response = yield client.fetch('https://books.toscrape.com')
self.on_response(response)
```

---

**Additional notes**:

Make your life easier by ditching `@gen.coroutine` and `yield` and switching to `async/await`:

```py
async def get(self):
    #arg = self.get_argument('stock')
    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = await client.fetch('https://books.toscrape.com')
    self.on_response(response)
```